# With ThisWorkbook Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

This script used to working in Office 2010, but since we upgraded to 2016, it no longer works. I have been playing with the code with no solution. Please help! :)

I have a weekly report I receive with orders and use VBA to format it into an Oracle format to upload without user intervention. I am opening the template file (PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx) and pasting it into a differently named report on a weekly basis (ThisWorkbook).

Runtime error 91: Object variable or with block not set

```
Sub templateOracleLoader()
    'Customer # Invoice Number  Sale Date   Prod. Name  Price   Sales Units Total   UPC number  Oracle Code Customer name (j)   PO# (k)
    'OPEN TEMPLATE
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    sPath = "C:\Users\douglas.futato\Desktop\"
    sFile = sPath & "PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    'COPY TEMPLATE PASTE IN BBU DOC
    Dim tmplt As Workbook
    Set tmplt = Workbooks("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
        tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet.paste
    End With
    'CLOSE TEMPLATE
    Windows("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `tmplt` from `tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets("INVOICE DETAILS")` leaving only `.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets("INVOICE DETAILS")`. See if this works.

Comment: @Mat'sMug He defines a variable as workbook, however it is still empty, then he is trying to use an active sheet from an unset workbook, throwing an error. I think he needs to remove that `tmplt` from the code, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

[(relevant to OP's revision 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46412904/1)

```
Dim tmplt As Workbook
```

That's declaring a `Workbook` variable.

```
tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets("INVOICE DETAILS")
```

That's referencing the `tmplt` object, which is still unassigned, i.e. its reference is `Nothing`: you can't invoke members on `Nothing`, hence, object reference is not `Set` -> run-time error 91.

Either `Set tmplt = {something}`, or figure out what you need to work with. There's not enough information in your post for us to guess exactly what you meant that to be doing. Did you mean to use `wb` instead of `tmplt`? If so, then replace `tmplt.ActiveSheet` with `wb.ActiveSheet`. If you meant to copy from `ThisWorkbook`, then do `.ActiveSheet`.

Note, I'm pretty sure you can't use `ActiveSheet` on a workbook that's not "active". Prefer working with `Worksheet` objects instead of `.Activate`ing stuff.

---

[(relevant to OP's revision 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46412904/2)

```
Dim tmplt As Workbook
Set tmplt = Workbooks("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx")
With ThisWorkbook
    tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet.paste
End With
'CLOSE TEMPLATE
Windows("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close False
```

Several things here. You want to close the `Workbook`, not the `Window`. So drop that part:

```
Windows("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close False
```

And replace it with:

```
tmplt.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Now, the `ActiveSheet` problem. Don't use `ActiveSheet`. Don't even qualify `ActiveSheet` with a `Workbook` object - just don't use `ActiveSheet`. The active sheet of a workbook you've just opened, is whatever worksheet happens to have been "active" when the workbook was last closed/saved: you have no guarantee that you're working with the sheet you need.

Use a `Worksheet` object instead, and *get* the sheet you need - explicitly:

```
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In tmplt.Worksheets
    If sh.CodeName = "Source" Then ' users can't easily tamper with CodeName.
        Set source = sh
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Now you have a rock-solid reference to the `Worksheet` you *know* you want (you can fetch it by index, or by name, but the user can usually trivially reorder worksheets, or rename the tabs, thwarting your efforts), use it:

```
source.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Note, you should do the same exercise to figure out your destination / `After` parameter.

Also note:

```
tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet.paste
```

`ActiveSheet.Paste` doesn't return anything, it's not legal there.

Comment: I changed it to this, but it is still not working:     Dim tmplt As Workbook
    Set tmplt = Workbooks("PRIMARY TEMPLATE - Desert Storm.xlsx")
    With ThisWorkbook
    tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With

Comment: @DougFresh again, your post does not provide enough information for us to guess what you intend to be doing. You need to clarify your question. Also "it's not working" is a pretty terrible problem description. I'd suggest you work with a specific `Worksheet` object instead of `ActiveSheet` - not sure you can even *use* `tmplt.ActiveSheet` without first activating the workbook.

Comment: copy a template sheet from a template file to weekly inbound reports

Comment: @DougFresh using `ActiveSheet` you're just copying whatever worksheet the workbook happens to have been last saved with - that's *begging* for problems to happen. Get a real `Worksheet` reference, and work off that.

Comment: This is not working either:     With ThisWorkbook
    wb.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With

Comment: Please, stop spamming me with "it's not working" and ask real solvable questions. Figure out what you want to do, stop trying nonsensical stuff and pinging me everytime. You want to copy a sheet - there's a **source** and there's a **destination**. Your still haven't edited your question to clarify what the source is supposed to be, and **we can't guess it for you**